# Обязательный порядок следования полей в node-soap

Tags: node.js, soap

Для интеграции с soap сервисом я использую nodejs библиотеку https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap и обнаружил с ней проблему, что передавая в нее параметры я должен соблюдать порядок следования полей при вызове soap метода. Обычно библиотеки сами выставляют поля в нужном порядке самостоятельно основываясь на главном xml файле soap, есть ли в этой библиотеке такой функционал? Если да то как его можно включить?

Comment: Хотел использовать github issue чтобы сообщить о данной проблеме разработчикам но эта возможность была отключена для этого проекта(

Comment: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#options-1 - параметры передал?

Comment: эти параметры я так понял для сервера, если ты свой soap сервис делаешь

Comment: @greshnikang привет! я смотрю ты имеешь опыть работы с либой soap. Посмотри пожалуйста вот этот вопрос, возможно ты сможешь помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043664/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-xml-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b5-soa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/pull/914 сделал этот функционал начиная с версии 0.19.0 будет работать автоматически