# Как создать несколько одноименных XML элементов на одном уровне в библиотеке soap?

Tags: node.js, soap

На проекте работаю с soap api.
Используем библиотеку [soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap).
Нужно передать что-то вроде этого:

```
<persons>
  <person name="Ivan"></person>
  <person name="Navi"></person>
</persons>
```

Для одного вложенного элемента передаю в качестве аргумента вот такой объект:

```
persons: {
  person: {
    attributes: {
      name: 'Ivan'
    }
  }
}
```

Как сделать два одноименных вложенных элемента, в доке не нашел.
Разработчики заблокировали раздел issue на гитхабе, так что там задать вопрос не смог.
Пробую передать массив, как я это делал в [xmlbuilder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder):

```
persons: {
  person: [
    {
      attributes: {
        name: 'Ivan'
      }
    },
    {
      attributes: {
        name: 'Navi'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Запрос возвращается с ошибкой `undefined: undefined`.

Как правильно сформировать запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

правильный ответ по моему мнению - послать к чертям либу soap и слать запросы при помощи axios. тело запроса можно сформировать любым удобным для вас способом, хоть при помощи шаблонной строки. я использую xmlbuilder. передать в конфиг заголовок SOAPAction или Content-Type: application/soap+xml (в зависимости от того насколько говняное говно используется на сервере к которому вы обращаетесь) рука не отвалится.

нюанс еще и в том, что когда мы перенесли приложение в k8s, то оказалось что библиотека soap работает в таком окружении некорректно (не помню уже в чем беда была), так что на axios мы в итоге переписали все запросы, даже те с которыми вопросов по синтаксису не возникало.